# Make Fluid disappear

Tags: texturing, particles, fluid-simulation

I am currently modeling a sword for a friend and I would like to animate a bloodline in the center of the sword... now is my problem, if I would do this by using a fluid, the fluid would be supposed to disappear at a point, cause its logically not flowing out of the sword...[image]

along this pit shall drop red fluid like an infinite cascade and disappear at the bottom. I did this pit by using a boolean, so I can imagin that I use this object again as boundary for the fluid, but how do I make the fluid infinitly come and go?

Or is there a was to make it with Texture particles to let it seem like its floating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a fluid simulation, correct? If so, try adding an outflow object at the bottom of the sword.

Comment: yup, that was the thing I was looking for and didnt know the name
thanks a lot